# phonegap line break in alert on Android

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have navigator.notification.alert("some text with phone number: 0-123-456-789") message for android.
The problem is that the phone number is broken into two lines, it looks like  this:

```
some text with phone
number: 0-123-456-
789
```

and I want a phone number not to be broken. The phone number is short enough to be displayed in one row. need to look like this:

```
some text with phone
number:
0-123-456-789
```

For example 0123456789 would be printed in one line without line break inside.

So how can I add a line break before the phone number for Android. \n does not work. it is displayed as text in alert message or the text before the \n is showed as one line and that's why its back part is hidden.

1) So the question is how to line break before the phone number?

2) Or how not to break the line on the phone number.

On iPhone \n works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: hey guys is there any possible way to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

```
\n\r
```

Worked for me on Android

```
navigator.notification.confirm('This will \n\r break', null, 'Title');
```

Comment: Only `\n` is required.